# Foreign key constraint on same table not allowing to delete on DB2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-zos

I have table named `VARIANT_LINK_BUILD_CHANGE` where primary key column name is `VARIANT_LINK_BUILD_CHANGE_OID` and foreign key is also in same table named `SWAP_VL_BUILD_CHANGE_OID`.

The data looks like this:

```
VARIANT_LINK_BUILD_CHANGE_OID    MOD_TYPE     SWAP_VL_BUILD_CHANGE_OID
    22269                         ADD           (null)
    27510                         DELETE        (null)
    32399                         DELETE        (null)
    32400                         MODIFY        (null)
```

Here , when I try to delete the above records using the query

```
DELETE FROM VARIANT_LINK_BUILD_CHANGE 
WHERE VARIANT_LINK_BUILD_CHANGE_OID IN  (22269, 27510, 32399, 32400);
```

I get this error:

> [Code: -532, SQL State: 23504]  THE RELATIONSHIP FK_VARIANT_LINK_BUILD_CHANGE_SWAP RESTRICTS THE DELETION OF ROW WITH RID X'000001270C'. SQLCODE=-532, SQLSTATE=23504, DRIVER=4.28.11

I am not sure why getting the above error since foreign key values are null. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, column  `SWAP_VL_BUILD_CHANGE_OID` has a FK constraint that references `VARIANT_LINK_BUILD_CHANGE_OID`. If so there must be some row where `SWAP_VL_BUILD_CHANGE_OID IN (22269, 27510, 32399, 32400)` that prevents the deletion of at least one of the rows you show

Comment: Check if the FK is defined appropriately for the requirements (whether by default or by explicit syntax), sometimes `on delete set null` is helpful, but much depends on the application .